# How to sum a row contains text, and each text is equal a given specific value in google spreadsheet

Tags: excel, function, google-sheets

In google spread sheet, Given the following:

```
John      5
Peter     0
Brad      3
Smith     1

Grade1    1
Grade2    2
Grade3    3
Grade4    4

Pass      5
Fail      0
```

I want to do the following, when I write in the same row say (John   Grad1   Pass), it should sum all values of each word, so I should get "11" in this case. Below some examples:

```
Peter  Grade2  Fail   2
Smith  Grade4  Pass   10
```

etc..

How can I do this?

Comment: could you please show us the code that you've tried for this task and where you are having trouble in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the raw data is in columns A and B, and your 3 search terms are in C1:E1, then you can use:

`=ArrayFormula(SUM(SUMIF(A:A;C1:E1;B:B)))`